# Can it be confirmed that Sample windows "Flight Application" in QTP is developed in Visual Basic?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vb6, qtp

Can it be confirmed that Sample windows "Flight Application" in QTP is developed in Visual Basic or "DOTNET" or VB-Dotnet?

Comment: What does the documentation say?  By the way, "DOTNET" (.NET is the proper way to refer to it) is the framework.  VB.NET (and C#) are languages in the framework.  Visual Basic is the non-OOP precursor to VB.NET.

Comment: This isn't really a good question suited to Stack Overflow. Why not Google it, or ask the QTP devs themselves. Technically it *can't* be written in *just* `dotnet` as it is a framework covering `VC++`, `VB.NET`, and `C#.NET`.

Comment: Hi, I meant C# .net only. 
Documentation does not say anything about it and even in google search results I can not find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use tasklist

```
tasklist /m /im someapp.exe
```

msvbvm60.dll is vb6, mscoresomething.dll is .NET.

Comment: mscoree.dll (and some extra padding characters)

Comment: `mscvr1xx.dll` is C++.

Comment: all theses .dll files are present with windows platform and it confirms the "VB" technology but does not specifically tells about the one technology(like Visual C++, VB6.0, C# .net etc) in which the application is developed.

Comment: Are you saying you get all those dlls listed by tasklist? I doubt that. You probably are looking at which dll files are present in the file system. But Bambi suggest that you look at the list of dll files that are present in memory (using the tasklist command provided) if you start the flight app. That´s the whole point of the answer. Of course all dlls are provided, i.e. installed by QTP in the file system.